# Connection refused error when trying to access http://metadata.google.internal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openshift

I'm getting connection refused error when trying to access `http://metadata.google.internal` from inside a pod running on OpenShift deployed on GCP:

```
sh-4.4$ curl 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/?recursive=true' -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to metadata.google.internal port 80: Connection refused
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the [documentation examples](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#querying) and use double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: Is access to Compute Engine metadata is allowed in your cluster? This link will help you: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/protecting-cluster-metadata